# plotly separation with many bin

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

Given grouped bins , is there a way of having a larger gap between the bins? in
I.e, in the desired output, every bar/bar group has a predefined space around it.

```
# Change the default stacking
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x="sex", y="total_bill",
             color='smoker', barmode='group',
             height=400)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building a figure you can adjust the gap between the bars like this:

```
fig.layout.bargap = 0.8
```

[image]

I've used `0.8` just to clearly illustrate the effects, but that number can be set to any int or float in the interval `[0, 1]`

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x="sex", y="total_bill",
             color='smoker', barmode='group',
             height=400)
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.layout.bargap = 0.8
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @verstland, I've tried bargap with the previous example of course, and I now understand why it didn't work previously.
For future reference -  if there are too many bars, plotly will not create the desired gap, **unless** you increase layout.width. if there is no space for the bargap, plotly quietly ignores the setting.

Comment: @DsCpp I see. Thank you for accepting my answer anyway. How many bars are we talking here?

Comment: I had 350 bars :D