# R plotly histogram increase bin width i.e. reduce margins between bins/ticks

Tags: r, plotly, histogram

How can I decrease the white space between the bins?

nbinsx  is an option but still there is some space remaining

```
  x1 <- rnorm(50)
  x2 <- rnorm(10)

fig <- plot_ly() 

fig <- fig %>% 
  
  add_histogram(x = ~x1, name = "X1", marker = list(color = "red")
  ) %>%
  
  add_histogram(x = ~x2, name = "X2", marker = list(color ="#blue")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: The white space is there to distinguish one set of bars from another.

Comment: I know but I assume thats editable as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plotly separation with many bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354456/plotly-separation-with-many-bin)

Comment: Yes worked! thx :)...added %>%
  
  layout(bargap = 0.8)